# chunks using python

Tags: python, nlp

I'm trying to extract all the proper nouns from a tagged paragraph. What I did in my code is that first I've extracted the paragraph separately and then I have checked whether there is any proper noun in it. But the problem is, I haven't been able to extract the proper noun. My code doesn't even go inside the loop where it checks for a specific tag.

My code:

```
def noun(sen):
m=[]
if (sen.split('/')[1].lower().startswith('np')&sen.split('/')[1].lower().endswith('np')):
         w=sen.strip().split('/')[0]
         m.append(w)
return m


import nltk
rp = open("tesu.txt", 'r')
text = rp.read()
list = []
sentences = splitParagraph(text)
for s in sentences:
 list.append(s)
```

Sample input from 'tesu.txt'

```
Several/ap defendants/nns in/in the/at Summerdale/np police/nn burglary/nn trial/nn      made/vbd statements/nns indicating/vbg their/pp$ guilt/nn at/in the/at.... 

Bellows/np made/vbd the/at disclosure/nn when/wrb he/pps asked/vbd Judge/nn-tl Parsons/np to/to grant/vb his/pp$ client/nn ,/, Alan/np Clements/np ,/, 30/cd ,/, a/at separate/jj trial/nn ./.
```

How can I extract all the tagged proper nouns from a paragraph?

Comment: Please show us an example tagged paragraph, otherwise we have no way to tell if your code is doing the right thing.

Comment: @DNA i have given a sample input..please check thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the data sample.

You need to:

- read each paragraph/line
- split the line by whitespace to extract each tagged word, e.g. `Summerdale/np`
- split the word by `/` to see if it is tagged `np`
- if so, add the other half of the split (the actual word) to your noun list

So something like the following (based on *Bogdan*'s answer, thanks!)

```
def noun(word):
    nouns = []
    for word in sentence.split():
      word, tag = word.split('/')
      if (tag.lower() == 'np'):
        nouns.append(word);
    return nouns

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nouns = []
    with open('tesu.txt', 'r') as file_p:
         for sentence in file_p.read().split('\n\n'): 
              result = noun(sentence)
              if result:
                   nouns.extend(result)
    print nouns
```

which for your example data, produces:

```
['Summerdale', 'Bellows', 'Parsons', 'Alan', 'Clements']
```

**Update**: In fact, you can shorten the whole thing down to this:

```
nouns = []
with open('tesu.txt', 'r') as file_p:
  for word in file_p.read().split(): 
    word, tag = word.split('/')
    if (tag.lower() == 'np'):
      nouns.append(word)
print nouns
```

if you don't care which paragraph the nouns come from.

You could also get rid of the `.lower()` if the tags are always lowercase as they are in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You should work on your code style. There are a lot of unnecessary loops in there I think. You also have a unnecessary method in `splitParagraph` that basically only calls the already existing `split` method, and you `import re` but never use it afterwards. Also ident you code, it's very hard to follow this way. You should provide a sample of the input from `"tesu.txt"` so we can help you more. Anyway all of your code there could be compact into:

```
 def noun(sentence);
    word, tag = sentence.split('/')
    if (tag.lower().startswith('np') and tag.lower().endswith('np')):
         return word
    return False

if __name__ == '__main__'
    words = []
    with open('tesu.txt', 'r') as file_p:
         for sentence in file_p.read().split('\n\n'): 
              result = noun(sentence)
              if result:
                   words.append(result)
```

Comment: thanks a lot..for your help. but if i try with your code it gives the error
    word, tag = sentence.split('/')
ValueError: too many values to unpack..and i have given sample input above